# How to check if current locale is equal to a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, symbols

I'm trying to determine whether to show the `Spanish` or `English` button on my web application.

```
<% if I18n.locale == 'es' %>
  <a href="<%= set_english_path %>" class="thin">English</a>
<% else %>
  <a href="<%= set_spanish_path %>" class="thin">Spanish</a>
<% end %>
```

The `if` condition **always** fails and the Spanish button is always displayed.

RubyMine show this upon inspection (during debugging):

[image]

So why is the comparison failing?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should use symbol instead of string when searching/comparing/setting locale. Try:

```
<% if I18n.locale == :es %>
```

Documentation for I18n is there http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Answer (score 3):

In my case

```
if I18n.locale.to_s == 'zh-CN'
  ...
```

did the trick.

Comment: I think this might be preferred: 

if I18n.locale.to_s == :'zh-CN'